# Polymorphic DLL exports

Tags: c++, winapi, interface, polymorphism, dllexport

I am currently working on a project that uses a DLL and an application that uses the DLL. The DLL is exported as an abstract base class header and a concrete implementation derived from the abstract base, as usual:

```
---- TaskInterface.h ----
class Task {
public:
    virtual int func1(void) = 0;
    virtual int func2(void) = 0;
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) Task * APIENTRY newTask();

--- Task.h ---
class TaskImpl : public Task
{
public:
    virtual int func1(void);
    virtual int func2(void):
};

Task * APIENTRY newTask()
{
    return static_cast<Task*>( new TaskImpl );
}

--- Task.cpp ---
int TaskImpl::func1(void)
{
 // ...
} 

int TaskImpl::func2(void)
{
  // ...
}
```

This works so far as intended, the application includes "AbstractTask.h" and then calls the respective function defined by class TaskImpl:

```
--- TheApplication.cpp ---
Task aTask = newTask();
aTask->func1();
aTask->func2();
// ...
```

However, now the Application discovers that what the default implementation in class TaskImpl does is not enough and therfore defines within its own scope a new derived class, like so:

```
--- AppImpl.h ---
#include "TaskInterface.h"

class AppImpl : public Task
{
  int func1(void) = { /* new stuff */ }
  int func2(void) = { /* new stuff */ }
};
```

and then defines in TheApplication.cpp:

```
--- TheApplication.cpp ---

#include "AppImpl.h"
ApplImp * aNewTask = static_cast<Task*>(newTask());

aNewTask->func1();
aNewTask->func2();
```

In what context do you think func1() and func2() are called? Correct: It's still the concrete implementation inside the DLL class TaskImpl and not the derivates defined by class AppImpl.

And basically this is my problem: I want to use a default implementation from inside a DLL, but I want to be able to expand it on the Application side, so unless I have explicitly overriden a function in ApplImp.h, I fall back to the one defined in TaskImpl inside the DLL.

Is this possible? If so, what am I doing wrong? If not, how could I accomplish something equivalent?

I already toyed with exporting both "TaskInterface.h" and "Task.h" and then have ApplImp.h include the concrete class in the DLL, but the compile doesn't like that for obvious reasons => can't export newTask() twice.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @dyp Yes, I omitted that for brevity. And while it's probably not pretty, the alternative would be shipping all the neccessary derivate classes with the DLL, which would mean that a) every time the Application needs an update so needs the DLL and b) the DLL carries a lot of useless application specific weight when it should just define a "lightweight" interface that can be extended at the users leisure.

Comment: Well that's just Undefined Behaviour, but I had to look up what the MSVC compiler says about this case. You should not cast from a base class pointer to a derived class pointer, if the dynamic type (= the type of the object *actually created*) is not a base class of the type you're casting to.

Answer (score 0):

As you need to allocate *and deallocate* via the DLL anyway, I'd suggest providing a wrapper class alongside the DLL. This wrapper class then could be designed to be inherited from.

```
class Task {
public:
    virtual int func1(void) = 0;
    virtual int func2(void) = 0;
};

//                       v~~~~v probably dllimport in the header you ship
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) Task * APIENTRY newTask();

class TaskWrapper {
public:
    TaskWrapper() : m_ptr( newTask() ) {}
    virtual ~TaskWrapper() { deleteTask(m_ptr); }

    virtual int func1(void) { m_ptr->func1(); }
    virtual int func2(void) { m_ptr->func2(); }

protected: // implementation omitted for brevity
    TaskWrapper(TaskWrapper const&);
    TaskWrapper(TaskWrapper&&);

    TaskWrapper& operator= (TaskWrapper const&);
    TaskWrapper& operator= (TaskWrapper&&);

private:
    Task* m_ptr; // preferably a unique_ptr
};
```

You could also let `TaskWrapper` derive from `Task`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want ApplImp to derive from TaskImp, and call into TaskImpl member implementations as needed, using standard C++ syntax..

You can't do that directly because the application and DLL are linked separately and have no compile-time knowledge of each other. The application doesn't know about TaskImpl at compile time, thus the compiler cannot derive from it and cannot create a Vtable that may be a combination of funcitons from application and DLL.

You chould compose the objects, i.e. create an instance of TaskImp inside ApplImp and delegate all functions to the TaskImp instance inside of ApplImp. That's inconvenient in many cases.

A more convenient way is to export the implementation of TaskImpl from the DLL: declare the whole class as __dllexport. Unfortunately, that's the least portable way to do it and in a large project, it may lead to a huge dll export section with 10000 C++-name-mangled entries. But you might be able to use TaskImpl as a base class in other DLLs or the application.

Btw, this won't compile because ApplImp is derived from Task, and Task* cannot be cast implicitly to ApplImpl.

> ApplImp * aNewTask = static_cast(newTask());